# Compare 2 keys in Java HashMap

Tags: java, generics, hashmap

I've made a `BinaryTree< HashMap<String, String> >.`

How can I compare the two keys so I can correctly insert the two elements (HashMaps) into  the ordered BinaryTree?
Here's what I've got so far:

```
public class MyMap<K extends Comparable<K>, V> extends HashMap<K, V> implements Comparable< MyMap<K, V> >
{

    @override
    public int compareTo(MyMap<K, V> mapTwo)
    {
        if ( (this.keySet().equals(mapTwo.keySet())) ) return 0;
        //How can I check for greater than/less than and keep my generics?  

    }
```

**EDIT:** There is only one key in each HashMap (it's a very simple language translation system), so sorting the keys shouldn't be necessary.  I would have liked to use the `String.compareTo()` method, but because of my generics, the compiler doesn't know that `K` is a `String`

Comment: Since you use String as keys you could iterate over each key and compare the string to the other.

Comment: Why don't you decorate the HashMap by wrapping it with another class and storing that class in the BinaryTree. Then you could use your classes 'compareTo' method to delegate to 'String.comparTo()'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've picked a bad data structure.

HashMaps are not naturally ordered.  The keys in the set for a HashMap have an unpredictable order that is sensitive to the sequence of operations that populated the map.  This makes it unsuitable for comparing two HashMaps.

In order to compare a pair of HashMaps, you need to extract the respective key sets, *sort them* and then compare the sorted sets.  In other words, a `compareTo` method for `HashSet` derived classes is going to be `O(NlogN)` on average.

---

FWIW, a `compareTo` implementation would look something like this, assuming that the method is to order the HashMaps based on the sorted lists keys in their respective key sets.  Obviously, there are other orderings based on the key sets.

```
public int compareTo(MyMap<K, V> other) {
    List<K> myKeys = new ArrayList<K>(this.keySet());
    List<K> otherKeys = new ArrayList<K>(other.keySet());
    Collections.sort(myKeys);
    Collections.sort(otherKeys);
    final int minSize = Math.min(myKeys.size(), otherKeys.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < minSize; i++) {
        int cmp = myKeys.get(i).compareTo(otherKeys.get(i));
        if (cmp != 0) {
            return cmp;
        }
    }
    return (myKeys.size() - otherKeys.size());
}
```

---

If there is only ever one key / value pair in the map, then you should replace it with a simple `Pair<K,V>` class.  Using a `HashMap` to represent a single pair is ... crazy.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.  I should have stated that there is only one String mapping to another in the HashMap, so the ordering of keys shouldn't be a problem.  I tried using the String.compareTo() method, but since at compile-time it's the paraameterized type 'K', the compiler doesn't know the key is a String

Comment: Your solution appears to be working, thanks.  Your `Pair` suggestion is a good idea, I don't know why I didn't think of that....

Comment: Calum can you post the complete working example here with main method as well.

Comment: @Deepak it's probably a bit too much to post here, but I can send you the relevant parts some other way perhaps?

Comment: @Deepak - The main point of my answer is that you shouldn't be using this data structure.  I'm not going to encourage bad software engineering by showing you how to do it.